# Difference Scala Class Declaration

Tags: scala, class, declaration

I want to ask what's the difference between these two Class Declarations below.

```
class Person(name: String, age: Int)
```

or

```
class Person() {
  var name: String = ""
  var age: Int = 0
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class Person(name: String, age: Int)
```

`name` and `age` are constructor parameters. As such they are:

- **required** - in order to create a `Person` instance
- **immutable** - the values cannot be changed
- **private** - (by default) and cannot be accessed via a class instance

---

```
class Person() {
  var name: String = ""
  var age: Int = 0
}
```

`name` and `age` are class data members. They are:

- **not specified during construction** - but are given the same default values for every `Person` instance
- **mutable** - because they are `var` variables
- **public** - (by default) and can be accessed and modified via a class instance

---

So, what's the difference? Almost everything.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! :)

Comment: @Lockna If one of the answers solves your problem, then please take a second to [accept an answer and mark the question as solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Ups, sorryy. 

Comment: Note that `Person(name: String, age: Int)` doesn't add `name` and `age` as class members (not even private ones), unless they're used inside a method (because then the compiler has to store that value somewhere). If you only use them to declare other variables at construction, the parameters will never become class members. In these cases they stay simple arguments to a method (the constructor), so it may be confusing to talk about them being public/private (or mutable/immutable, but even the compiler mentions vals if you try to mutate an argument).

Comment: @francoisr While it's technically true in this particular case, the description of `name` and `age` as "immutable" and "private" is probably more useful in every non-pathological case where `name` and `age` are actually used inside of `Person` somewhere. If they are used (most of the time, presumably), they are indeed implemented as `private` `final` fields. Try it out with `class Person(name: String, age: Int) { override def toString = name + age }; classOf[Person].getDeclaredFields`.

Comment: That's what I said in my comment. However, they are *not* declared as members if they're only used in the constructor, eg. to initialise other `vars`. The distinction is just a technicality anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The first declaration uses `name` and `age` as constructor arguments, but they do not become members of the class, that is you can't write `person.name`.

For a beginner, the second line can be considered a more complicated way to write `class Person(var name: String = " ", var age: Int = 0)`. It actually doesn't translate to exactly the same thing: your version creates a class that has a single constructor argument and two public variables, while mine has a constructor with 2 arguments that have default values. Unless you have a good reason to declare it your way, it's usually better to write:

```
val person = new Person("Andrew", 11)
```

than

```
val person = new Person()
person.name = "Andrew"
person.age = 11
```

which is what your second version would force you to do.

Note that in Scala, you will mostly be using values (constants) and not variables, so you'd actually typically use `class Person(val name: String = " ", val age: Int = 0)`. For simple data types like this, people typically use a `case class`:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
```

In this case, both argument are considered public and immutable. The only way to modify a person's name is to create another instance of `Person` with the new name:

```
val andrew = Person("Andrew", 11)
val will = andrew.copy(name="Will") # Will is also 11
```

Case classes will automatically give you proper `equals` and `hashCode` implementation, as well as the `copy` method I used above. You can easily find more infos about them on the internet.

Comment: The second version is not at all equivalent to what you wrote there. `class P2(var name: String = " ", var age: Int = 0)` creates a class `P2` with a rather complicated constructor with two default arguments, whereas the original `class P1() { var name: String = " "; var age: Int = 0 }` creates a class with a much simpler nullary constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! :)

Comment: @AndreyTyukin You are right, but from the question I'm also assuming that the author is new to Scala, so I didn't want to be too explicit. I will edit the answer to clarify.

Comment: @francoisr You didn't have to be "too explicit", because you didn't have to say anything about default arguments or case classes in the first place. The question does not ask anything about default arguments or case classes, so I'm not sure what almost the entire posting (with the exception of the very first sentence) has to do with the question, to be honest?

Comment: IMHO, the question is probably asked by a Scala newcomer, so rather than only answering the question itself, I'm suggesting other more idiomatic ways to express what I believe the author is trying to do. Do you still not agree with my answer being correct?